# Get a list of one column from a SOQL result

Tags: apex, soql

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
List<String> names = new List<String>();
for(Account a:accList) {
    names.add(a.Name);
}
```

Say I have 30,000 Account records and I want to get all the Account records Name field in a list,
Is there a way of getting list of only account records Name field instead looping though the list of SOQL and adding Name field to another List.

Comment: I did do peformance analysis with this code:

List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10000];
List<String> names = new List<String>();
for(Account a:accList) {
    names.add(a.Name);
}
System.debug('Time: '+ Limits.getCPUTime());

Output : 
Time: 530

________________________________________

Set<String> uniqueNames = new Map<String,SObject> (
    [SELECT Name Id FROM Account Group By Name LIMIT 10000]
  ).keySet();
System.debug('Time: '+ Limits.getCPUTime());

Output:
Time: 112


So using Aggregate is better than running a for loop in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Derek's answer ...

You can do the following:

```
Set<String> uniqueNames = new Map<String,SObject> (
    [SELECT Name Id FROM Account Group By Name]
  ).keySet();
```

Grouping By Name works fine unless the name is an AutoNumber field which for `Account`, it is not. Aggregate queries will fail on extremely large record sets so using additional WHERE clauses is advised.

Reference: [Building a Keyset from any field](https://www.xbaf.com/field-keysets)

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I have around 20,000 records that I need to pull even after using WHERE clauses, Is it safe to use Aggregate queries to pull  around 15 - 20k records ?

Comment: should be OK but use execute anonymous and try!

Comment: I did do peformance analysis with this code:

List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10000];
List<String> names = new List<String>();
for(Account a:accList) {
    names.add(a.Name);
}
System.debug('Time: '+ Limits.getCPUTime());

Output : 
Time: 530

_________________________

Set<String> uniqueNames = new Map<String,SObject> (
    [SELECT Name Id FROM Account Group By Name LIMIT 10000]
  ).keySet();
System.debug('Time: '+ Limits.getCPUTime());

Output:
Time: 112


So using Aggregate is better than running a for loop in this scenario.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, obviously as the aggregate queries are optimized to use the Salesforce underlying database handlers at platform level and automatically takes care of plugging the Name in <String, sObject> by hashMap, rather than when you iterate them separately using a for loop, you are just relying on the for-loop iterative optimizations.

Very good observation.

Comment: as a service to the community you should accept either Derek's or my answer if you're satisfied (use the check mark to the left of the answer)

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't really any other solution than to use a loop. SOQL returns SObjects by design and we can't modify that.

Even if you use the AggregateResult aliasing trick (which is probably not possible with a general string field like `Name`), there's still a loop running behind the scenes.

Loops are *the* way to handle collections of data. About the only suggestion that could be made here is to use a SOQL for loop instead of storing the results of the query in a separate list that you then feed into your loop.

Comment: Clarification: The SOQL for loop approach is better from a "lines of code" and heap space standpoint (SOQL for loops internally operate on 200 records at a time, so you aren't trying to keep _all_ of the results in the heap). Useful when you don't need the SObject records later in code. Based on some writing by [James from Joys of Apex on writing performant tests](https://www.jamessimone.net/blog/joys-of-apex/writing-performant-apex-tests/) (no affiliation), getting an iterator instance and using a `while` loop is the approach for fast execution.